# D7 Services node view mode

Tags: 7, services

I am using the services module. When I call domain.com/json/node/3 is it possible to ask for a specific view mode of the node ?

Something like this ?

domain.com/json/node/teaser/3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nope, Drupal Services just return the node object by default. Looking at the end points in node_resource.inc, it would seem it would not be hard to build thou.

Comment: If youre building it try using the services output alter hook. http://drupalcode.org/project/services.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/docs/services.alter.api.php#l29

Comment: Perfect! I did not see that function. This is just what I need.

Comment: Maybe afterwards I should write some docs for services. It is a good and important module, but the documentation could use a lot of work.

Comment: looking forward to the added documentation